# R - sparse.model.matrix error message

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, r-caret

I'm trying to convert a large, dense data.frame with a bunch of factor variables to a sparse.model.matrix.  I've been getting a bunch of error messages and decided to replicate the examples in the docs.  Below is the output.

I've tried restarting and reinstalling the `Matrix` package.

Any suggestions for what could be wrong?

CODE:

```
library(Matrix)
dd <- data.frame(a = gl(3,4), b = gl(4,1,12))# balanced 2-way
options("contrasts") # the default:  "contr.treatment"
sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd)
sparse.model.matrix(~ -1+ a + b, dd)# no intercept --> even sparser
sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd, contrasts = list(a="contr.sum"))
sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd, contrasts = list(b="contr.SAS"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
> library(Matrix)
> dd <- data.frame(a = gl(3,4), b = gl(4,1,12))# balanced 2-way
> options("contrasts") # the default:  "contr.treatment"
$contrasts
   unordered      ordered 
"contr.ltfr" "contr.poly" 

> sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd)
Error in get(contrasts.arg) : object 'contr.ltfr' not found
> sparse.model.matrix(~ -1+ a + b, dd)# no intercept --> even sparser
Error in get(contrasts.arg) : object 'contr.ltfr' not found
> sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd, contrasts = list(a="contr.sum"))
Error in get(contrasts.arg) : object 'contr.ltfr' not found
> sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd, contrasts = list(b="contr.SAS"))
Error in get(contrasts.arg) : object 'contr.ltfr' not found
> 
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
> dd <- data.frame(a = gl(3,4), b = gl(4,1,12))# balanced 2-way
> options("contrasts") # the default:  "contr.treatment"
$contrasts
   unordered      ordered 
"contr.ltfr" "contr.poly" 

> sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd)
Error in model.spmatrix(t, data, transpose = transpose, drop.unused.levels = drop.unused.levels,  : 
  no slot of name "i" for this object of class "dgeMatrix"
> sparse.model.matrix(~ -1+ a + b, dd)# no intercept --> even sparser
Error in model.spmatrix(t, data, transpose = transpose, drop.unused.levels = drop.unused.levels,  : 
  no slot of name "i" for this object of class "dgeMatrix"
> sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd, contrasts = list(a="contr.sum"))
Error in model.spmatrix(t, data, transpose = transpose, drop.unused.levels = drop.unused.levels,  : 
  no slot of name "i" for this object of class "dgeMatrix"
> sparse.model.matrix(~ a + b, dd, contrasts = list(b="contr.SAS"))
Error in model.spmatrix(t, data, transpose = transpose, drop.unused.levels = drop.unused.levels,  : 
  no slot of name "i" for this object of class "dgeMatrix"
```

SessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] data.table_1.10.4 xgboost_0.6-4     sqldf_0.4-11      RSQLite_2.0       gsubfn_0.6-6      proto_1.0.0       Metrics_0.1.2    
 [8] gbm_2.1.3         survival_2.41-3   cluster_2.0.6     ade4_1.7-8        convPkg5_0.1      RODBC_1.3-14      caret_6.0-73     
[15] ggplot2_2.2.1     lattice_0.20-35   Matrix_1.2-11    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10           compiler_3.4.1         nloptr_1.0.4           plyr_1.8.4             iterators_1.0.8       
 [6] tools_3.4.1            digest_0.6.12          bit_1.1-12             lme4_1.1-12            memoise_1.0.0         
[11] tibble_1.3.4           nlme_3.1-131           gtable_0.2.0           mgcv_1.8-17            rlang_0.1.2           
[16] foreach_1.4.3          DBI_0.6-1              microbenchmark_1.4-2.1 SparseM_1.76           stringr_1.2.0         
[21] MatrixModels_0.4-1     bit64_0.9-5            stats4_3.4.1           grid_3.4.1             nnet_7.3-12           
[26] tcltk_3.4.1            minqa_1.2.4            blob_1.1.0             reshape2_1.4.2         car_2.1-4             
[31] magrittr_1.5           scales_0.4.1           codetools_0.2-15       ModelMetrics_1.1.0     MASS_7.3-47           
[36] pbkrtest_0.4-7         colorspace_1.3-2       quantreg_5.29          stringi_1.1.3          lazyeval_0.2.0        
[41] munsell_0.4.3          chron_2.3-51
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get any error when I ran your code... maybe try restarting R in case it's something else in your environment that's causing the problem? I got a bunch of pretty sparse matrices when I ran this.

Comment: where did `contr.ltfr` come from - afaik its not in base R - have you loaded other packages / workspace  / defined it?

Comment: @user20650 Makes a good point. When I ran this mine said `$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 
`

Comment: yup, try redefining them to the standard `options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly" ))`

Comment: It looks somehow related to caret?  Found this here: https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/380

Comment: Yes, it's from caret. A few other packages have it, but that's where you're probably getting it from.